# Can 'expressionValueWithObject' method interpret numbers as floats instead of integers?

Tags: objective-c

I am making a calculator that logs input in a label named "inputLabel' and then outputs the answer in a different label named "outputLabel" (similar to a graphing calculator).  Once the user is finished entering the expression, the expression is stored in an NSString object and then parsed with the NSPredicate class and evaluated with the NSExpression class.  What I have works, but I have noticed for particular operations the answers are not correct.  For example, if the user types in "25/2" the calculator returns 12, which is obviously incorrect.  However, if the user types in "25/2.0" or "25.0/2" the calculator returns 12.5 which is what I want.  It seems that the NSExpression method 'expressionValueWithObject' is interpreting the operands as integers instead of floats.  If this is the case, is there a way that I change the 'expressionValueWithObject'method to interpret the operands as floats?

Brain.m

```
-(float)performCalculation: (NSString *)operation
{
    NSPredicate *parsed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[operation stringByAppendingString:@"=1.0"]];
    NSExpression *inputExpressionParsed = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)parsed leftExpression];
    NSNumber *result = [inputExpressionParsed expressionValueWithObject:inputExpressionParsed context:nil];

    return [result floatValue];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)equalsPressed:(id)sender
{
    //self.inputLabel.text = [self.inputLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@".0"];
    NSString *inputExpression = self.inputLabel.text;
    self.inputLabel.text = [self.inputLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@"="];
    float result = [self.brain performCalculation:inputExpression];
    self.outputLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `NSExpression` cannot do that. You could try to append ".0" to all integer numbers
in the string before evaluating it, but the better solution is probably to use a "proper"
math expression parser, for example
https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser

Comment: Thanks for response.  I've added DDMathParser to my project, but I have no idea how to use it.  Is there documentation that shows how to use DDMathParser or something that shows which methods are available for use?

Comment: @user2954945: Did you read https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki ? There are links to the operator list, function list, and various usage examples.

Comment: Well I looked it over again and found what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the expression tree replacing the expression with the integer value (expressionType == NSConstantExpression). It depends a little bit of the features of your calculator, whether it is worth or not.